# Referencing an object using the this keyword within a method?

Tags: java

How would I reference an object using the this keyword with in the mouseEntered method?
As the this keyword seams to be referencing the mouseAdapter Class?

```
public class JButtonx extends JButton {
public String name;
public JButtonx(String xe) {
    this.name = xe;
    this.setText(this.name);
    this.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
    this.setBounds(346, 6, 88, 25);
    this.setOpaque(true);
    this.setBackground(new Color(100,100,100));
    this.setFocusPainted(false);

    this.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            //The error occures here.
            this.setBackground(new Color(100,100,100));

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: `JButtonx.this` to reference items in `JButtonx` I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within a nested class you can omit the `this` keyword and just use the name of a method or field.  A non-static nested class will have access to the fields and methods of the outer class.

```
this.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        setBackground(new Color(100,100,100));
    }
});
```

As others have suggested you can place the class name before `this` and then invoke the method.  This form is more verbose and may be easier to follow, it also allows you to specify between two methods or fields that have the same name in both the outer and nested class.

```
this.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        JButtonX.this.setBackground(new Color(100,100,100));
    }
});
```

To research more about field and method access in nested classes checkout the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Comment: Is there any benefit to doing this over using JButtonx.this? Just curious.

Comment: I find the JButtonx.this 'better' myself from a self-documenting code perspective as it 100% removes any ambiguity of which setBackground() method you wanted to call. But its personal preference.

Comment: @Gimby I agree its personal preference, except when the outer class and nested class contain a field or method with the same name.  In that circumstance the `Class.this` syntax is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Altough Kevin Bowersox's answer is better because you really should not do this here is what you were looking for:

```
    this.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        Classname.this.setBackground()...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the `this` refers to the anonymous inner class you implemented, i.e, instance of `MouseAdapter` and you are using `this` in the respective overridden method ,so obviously `this` refers to instance of `MouseAdapter`

So Change to `YourClassName.this`

```
this.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        //The error occures here.
        JButtonX.this.setBackground(new Color(100,100,100));

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the JButtonx's this by using `JButtonx.this` . Another way is to write a method like

```
public void setHoverState(){
    this.setBackground(new Color(100,100,100));
}
```